# How can I create a security group in LDAP server?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I am trying create a security group in LDAP server using unbounded-ldap-sdk but whenever I am trying to query the group with below filter, it is not returning the group.

Filter: `(&(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648)(cn=test_group*))`

The group is:

`dn: CN=bpa,DC=developer,DC=tester,DC=example,DC=com
objectClass: group
groupType: -2147483646
instanceType: 4
objectClass: top
objectCategory: Group
cn: test_group
distinguishedName: CN=bpa,DC=developer,DC=tester,DC=example,DC=com
description: test group for testing
name: test_group`

Code to query the server:

```
javax.naming.directory.SearchControls searchControls = new javax.naming.directory.SearchControls();
searchControls.setReturningAttributes({'name', 'cn'});
searchControls.setSearchScope(javax.naming.directory.SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

DirContext.search("DC=developer,DC=tester,DC=example,DC=com", filter, searchControls);
```

Could you please help me to find out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is complicated. Microsoft Active Directory classifies [Groups](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Groups) in several different methods.

GroupType is a bitmask attribute.

The group type in your entry is groupType: -2147483646 which is a Global Security Group.

I see nothing wrong with your LDAP filter or the group. However, you do not show the baseDN of the group search or if you are querying the Global Catalog. You could have an issue with LDAP referrals being returned.

Comment: Hello @jwilleke, I have updated the description with the code. Please note that `dc=com` was passed as base DN during LDAP server creation.

Comment: What is the context of the user performing the search?